# Equivalent condition to exactness

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, injective-module

Let $I$ be an injective $R$-module. Is it true that a short sequence of $R$-modules
$$0\rightarrow A'\rightarrow A\rightarrow A''\rightarrow 0$$ is exact if and only if $$ 0\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(A'',I)\rightarrow\text{Hom}(A,I)\rightarrow\text{Hom}(A',I)\rightarrow 0$$ is exact? I'm interested particularly in the case $R =\mathbb{Z}$ and $I = \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Obviously  the forward direction follows directly from $I$ being injective, I'm curious about the converse.

Comment: The converse is false in general. Consider any non-exact sequence of finite abelian groups, and choose $I$ to be some Prüfer group (which is an injective abelian p-group) with respect to some prime p not dividing any of the group orders. Then the Hom-sequence become zero (in particular exact). For the special case $I = \mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}$ however, I think the converse might be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injective modules that satisfy this property are called *faithfully injective*,  which is equivalent to being an injective cogenerator in the category of $R$-modules.

Since $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is faithfully injective over any ring, it holds over $\mathbb{Z}$.

More generally, one can consider what are called *faithfully exact* functors, which are functors $T:R\text{-Mod}\to S\text{-Mod}$ such that $T(A)\to T(B)\to T(C)$ is exact if and only if $A\to B\to C$ is exact.  You are just considering the case of the functor $\text{Hom}(-,I)$.

[The original paper on this subject is by Ishikawa](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1118801336), and it is very readable and comprehensive, including giving a treatment of faithfully injective modules.